# Angular using # in URLS

Tags: angular, url, ietf

I'm currently working on a URL parser that formats and corrects relative links. I designate some characters to be special and included is "#".

I found that this becomes an issue when I'm processing pages that are developed with Angular, because makes use of #'s in the URL. However, in reading up on the [IETF protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738) for URL naming, it seems like #'s are reserved characters.

Can someone explain to me how Angular interacts with URL naming?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

#### Routing strategy

When configuring application routing in an angular project one can choose between regular HTML5 routing (`PathLocationStrategy`) or "hash-style URL" routing (`HashLocationStrategy`).

The default is `PathLocationStrategy` but hash-style routes can be implemented by passing `{useHash: true}` as the second parameter to the `RouterModule.forRoot()` function

According to Angular's official documentation regarding [LocationStrategy and browser URL styles](https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles):

> Older browsers send page requests to the server when the location URL changes unless the change occurs after a "#" (called the "hash"). Routers can take advantage of this exception by composing in-application route URLs with hashes.

#### Why does Angular support hash routes

A `#` in a URL represents an anchor identifier ([RFC1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738)) and is very useful when linking to specific content within a page.

What angular *exploits* with the `HashLocationStrategy` is the fact that **any content after the `#` symbol isn't send to a server** - which makes it ideal to use it for storing application state.

#### Why is it useful

With hash routes a page reload (or revisit through bookmark) on a subpage like

`http://localhost:4200/#/articles/35`

doesn't query the server for the subpage, but instead returns the main application page

`http://localhost:4200/`

This way the server implementation only needs to know about the root page (which is the only thing that'll ever be queried)

Using the `PathLocationStrategy` (default) the server needs to be set up to handle requests for every single URL your application implements.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This makes a lot of sense!